# Drupal for facebook, connect button disappearing. Please help?

Tags: social-network

My facebook connect button keeps disappearing.  Sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not and when it is it's only on the homepage.  My site address is www.idahorealestatereview.com.  Not sure how to fix this. I've read the README file, and followed the instructions. I am not sure what I'm missing.

The block is implemented by a module (Drupal for Facebook). I checked, and the block input format is full HTML.

Comment: please make sure block input filter is full html or php

Comment: Is that block implemented by a module you installed?

Comment: The input format used for a block is not the explanation of why a block vanishes. In the case then the block is provided by a module, it is not possible to alter the input format used by that block, for the simple reason there isn't an input format, in those cases.